# Animating with curves in greensock

Tags: gsap

Is it possible to animate objects so they move along a curved path, using green sock?

I would prefer to use greensock over jquery as I heard that greensock is much more efficient for animation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, there is [BezierPlugin](https://greensock.com/bezierplugin-js/), which was replaced by [MotionPathPlugin](https://greensock.com/motionpath) in GSAP 3

Answer (score 0):

You can use BezierPlugin
(http://api.greensock.com/js/com/greensock/plugins/BezierPlugin.html)

example :

```
    var path = [{x:"+=200",y:"+=100"},
                {x:"+=100",y:"+=300"},
                {x:"+=0",y:"+=0"}
               ];
    TimelineLite.to("#elem",5,{bezier:{autoRotate:true,curviness:2,values:path}});
```

https://codepen.io/tvalentius/pen/rezzrv